# OOP Principle Differences between Interfaces and Abstract Classes

Tags: oop, interface, abstract

I understand that Abstract Classes are classes that contain declared methods that do not all necessarily have a specified implementation because the code would have to be declared in the child class instead but Im finding it difficult to understand the OOP concept behind the introduction of Interfaces.

What are the architectural and principle differences between interfaces and abstract classes if the abstract class has no defined methods and states (Aside from the fact that abstract classes can have constructors)?

In addition, why should anyone use abstract classes and interfaces in the first place? I understand that it adds restrictions to your code not allowing people to defined subclasses without specified methods but the code would work in the exact same way if the non implemented declared methods were not present in the interface and abstract class. So what is the implied benefit of writing methods with no implementation only to implement it later in the subclass?

**I have seen many posts on Interface vs Abstract Classes but im interested in the principle differences between the two, not their functional differences.**

Comment: To me interface is a means to enforce contract with the consumer of the API - for .e.g. a car interface - should have four wheels, should have steering wheel - no exceptions. Where as abstract classes are to abstract behavior of an object like for e.g. a living thing - an object very abstract that  there are many varied behaviors. So represent a living thing as abstract class

Comment: did you google this first? this topic has been done to death here, surely there are existing answers that address this.

Comment: I did google it... to death as well. I still havent gone through that 'Aha' moment and im struggling

Comment: more explaining may not help then. my advice is look at examples in the jdk libraries'  source code, start with java.util, see how java.util.List, ArrayList, and AbstractList work, maybe see java.sql. java.io has good examples of using interfaces in a Decorator pattern..

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to my own question after a year, I have discovered the answer that I wanted.

A class, regardless of being abstract or not, always tries to define/design what entities look like from their behaviour to their states. In the case of an abstract class, we are modelling an idea/entity that we do not want to be instantiated during run time. Example, if we had  an app about dogs and cats, we may want to define what an animal is and then extend this idea to define what a dog/cat is by extending our base animal class. An animal object will never be instantiated but a dog/cat will.

An interface on the other hand are a set of methods that represents some form of interactions to be expected from any class. As long as a class implements an interface, you know what methods to expect from it. Thus, you can have two entities (classes) that do not relate to one another that implement the same interface. Example, a dog and person class may both implement a 'digest' interface. This means that they are all able to digest food as we have explicitly stated what functions to expect in the interface to enable food digestion behaviour. Obviously the details of the implementation differs thus the functions defined in the interface are outlined in the classes implementing them.